# write a python program to input a number and count the occurrence of a given number in a given list

Tags: python, project

I need an answer for this question
can u guys hel me

I tried this

```
lst=[]
n = int(input("Enter number of elements :"))
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
lst.count(ele)
print(lst)
```

cant get answer for the question

Answer (score 1):

Seems very straightforward solution to me. You just need to loop through your given list and compare each element with the number you want to check. Just increment the count in case of if condition satisfies.

```
given_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 65, 6, 4, 5, 4 , 4, 6, 2]

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

count = 0
for number in given_lst:
    if number == num:
        count += 1

print(f"Total occurrence: {count}")
```

Comment: This a good way to answer to solve the problem but a tip in general try to wrap you code into function so you can reuse if you need to